# How to replace 0 values with mean based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, replace, transform

I have a dataframe with two features: gps_height (numeric) and region (categorical).

The gps_height contains a lot of 0 values, which are missing values in this case. I want to fill the 0 values with the mean of the coherent region.

My reasoning is as follows:
1. Drop the zero values and take the mean values of gps_height, grouped by region

```
df[df.gps_height !=0].groupby(['region']).mean()
```

But how do I replace the zero values in my dataframe with those mean values?

Sample data:

gps_height  region
0  1390       Iringa
1  1400       Mara
2  0          Iringa
3  250        Iringa
...

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'region':list('aaabbbccc'),
                   'gps_height':[2,3,0,3,4,5,1,0,0]})
print (df)
  region  gps_height
0      a           2
1      a           3
2      a           0
3      b           3
4      b           4
5      b           5
6      c           1
7      c           0
8      c           0
```

Replace `0` to missing values, and then replace `NAN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `mean`s by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)per groups:

```
df['gps_height'] = df['gps_height'].replace(0, np.nan)
df['gps_height']=df['gps_height'].fillna(df.groupby('region')['gps_height'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
  region  gps_height
0      a         2.0
1      a         3.0
2      a         2.5
3      b         3.0
4      b         4.0
5      b         5.0
6      c         1.0
7      c         1.0
8      c         1.0
```

Or filter out `0` values, aggregate `means` and map all `0` rows:

```
m = df['gps_height'] != 0
s = df[m].groupby('region')['gps_height'].mean()
df.loc[~m, 'gps_height'] = df['region'].map(s)
#alternative
#df['gps_height'] = np.where(~m, df['region'].map(s), df['gps_height'])
print (df)
  region  gps_height
0      a         2.0
1      a         3.0
2      a         2.5
3      b         3.0
4      b         4.0
5      b         5.0
6      c         1.0
7      c         1.0
8      c         1.0
```

Comment: Two very nice solutions!

However, the NaN values of gps_height are still there and not replaced.

Comment: @NielsHoogeveen - Can you add data sample? Missing values are `NaN`s?

Comment: The missing values were 0, I replaced them with NaN as you said. Works perfect. 

But the second step won't do. I expected a number for the rows with gps_height is NaN, but I still get NaN at those rows.

Comment: @NielsHoogeveen - Maybe `NaNs` are strings, try `df['gps_height'] = pd.to_numeric(df['gps_height'], errors='coerce')` as first step od solution. It replace non numeric to NaNs.

Comment: If here `groupby` multiple columns, how could I modify this line: `df['gps_height'] = np.where(~m, df['region'].map(s), df['gps_height'])`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up facing the same problem that @ahbon raised: what if there are more than one column to group by? And this was the closest question that I found to my problem. After a serious struggle, I came to a solution.

As far as I know (there are `pandas` specific functions to do similar things) It could not be an elegant/orthodox one, so I'd appreciate some feedback.

There it goes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list('a'*4+'b'*4+'c'*4+'d'*4),
                  "B":list('xy'*8),
                  "C":random.sample(range(17), 16)})
print(df)

    A  B   C
0   a  x   1
1   a  y   8
2   a  x  16
3   a  y  12
4   b  x   6
5   b  y   4
6   b  x  14
7   b  y   0
8   c  x  13
9   c  y   5
10  c  x   2
11  c  y   9
12  d  x  10
13  d  y  11
14  d  x   3
15  d  y  15
```

First get the indices of `0` values to retrieve the non zero data and get the mean by group.

```py
idx = list(df[df["C"] != 0].index)
data_to_group = df.iloc[idx,]
grouped_data = pd.DataFrame(data_to_group.groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].mean())
```

And now the tricky part. Here is where I get the impression that it could be a more elegant solution:

- Stack, unstack and reset index
- Then merge with the subset of rows in `df` where `C` is `0`; drop `C` from the first and keep `C` from the second
- Finaly update `df` with this subset with no zero in `C`.

```py
grouped_data = grouped_data.stack().unstack().reset_index()
zero_rows = df[df.C == 0]
zero_rows_replaced = pd.merge(left = zero_rows, right = grouped_data, 
                              how = "left", on=["A", "B"],
                              suffixes=('_x','')).drop('C_x', axis=1)
zero_rows_replaced = zero_rows_replaced.set_index(zero_rows.index.copy())
df.update(zero_rows_replaced)
print(df)

    A  B   C
0   a  x   1
1   a  y   8
2   a  x  16
3   a  y  12
4   b  x   6
5   b  y   4
6   b  x  14
7   b  y   4
8   c  x  13
9   c  y   5
10  c  x   2
11  c  y   9
12  d  x  10
13  d  y  11
14  d  x   3
15  d  y  15
```